# Excel how to use the `Y-m-d H:i:s` validation

Tags: excel, validation, datetime, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I use phpspreadsheet to write a xlsx file for user to import their data. And use custom datetime validation to validate the datetime field.

```
$datetime_validation = new DataValidation();
$datetime_validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$datetime_validation->setErrorTitle("unsupported datetime format");
$datetime_validation->setError("please input datetime in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'(2020-09-12 13:56:00)");
$datetime_validation->setAllowBlank(false);
$datetime_validation->setType("custom");
$datetime_validation->setFormula1("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

But when I input like `2020-12-12 23:00:00`, it prompt the error says the input data is not match the format.

Comment: I refer to this [Custom Date Formatting Characters](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time-formatting#:~:text=Custom%20Excel%20Date%20and%20Time%20Formatting.%201%20Select,select%20from%20in%20the%20'Type'%20list%20...%20)

Comment: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" is not a valid formula so I'm guessing it only matches that string exactly instead of matching dates.  This page https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3653-excel-only-allow-date-in-cell.html suggests setting the formula to `=AND(ISNUMBER(B2),LEFT(CELL("format",B2),1)="D")`